# Shopify_api gem install 403 ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess in HomeController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, shopify

I just installed the `shopify_api gem` and generated a placeholder app.

Once I visit `localhost:3000` and enter my stores url I get the following in in `HomeController#index` error:

```
ActiveResource::ForbiddenAccess .
```

I have determined it is coming from this line in `home_controller.rb`

```
@orders   = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(:all)
```

Commenting this out solves the issue. 
It looks like some kind of permission is not working with the orders.

My domain in my app settings matches `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you followed the [Getting Started](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api#getting-started) steps at in the README for the shopify_api gem, because until you do ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session) your request won't have the required authentication.  This is why you are getting a 403 (i.e. ForbiddenAccess) error response.

In this case you are listing orders, in which case you need the read_orders scope if you are using oauth2 authentication.  See the [Authentication](http://api.shopify.com/authentication.html) page in the API docs for a list of scopes and where they are needed.

Edit: Realized that 403 response is for missing access (i.e. scope), rather than 401 which would be authentication.

Comment: Just to add in more detail, check the specifics about the scope parameter. To say what the app needs access to.

Comment: Ah I see. When I am reinstalling the default app, the only item it says is 'Read Products' and that is a paramater in the URL 'scope=read_product'

I've been looking everywhere in the rails app to see where I can alter the scope, but I cannot find it.

Any idea how I can modify the scope in that url?

Comment: If you're using the shopify_app gem there's a file in `config/initializers` called `omniauth.rb`. That's where the scopes are defined.

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Think I figured it out. For anyone looking for the format, you can see a reference for it [https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2#configuring](https://github.com/Shopify/omniauth-shopify-oauth2#configuring)